# C++ Implementing Functions that don't utilize global declarations

Tags: c++, function, vector

My code is already working, seen here: http://pastebin.com/mekKRQkG

Right now, my functions work but utilizing information that I've declared `globally`, I guess, and I want to convert them so that they are in the format as seen on `lines 11-15`, but I'm unsure of how to convert them to do so.  Simply put, I'm trying to convert my function of

`"void add_county_election_file"`

to be in the format of

`"void add_county_election_file(const string, const vector &, const vector &, const vector &, const vector &)"`

and I have no idea where to begin or how to even start.

Could someone please help me out and show me how I'd do this for the first function, so I can implement it across the board?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function declaration should look something like this:

```
void add_county_election_file(const string, vector<int>&, vector<string>..);
```

Make sure that your argument list for the vector template is correct(that's the type you put between <>)

Then match the implementation of you function to the declaration:

```
   void add_county_election_file(const string, vector<int>&, vector<string>..){...}
```

Now call your function with apppropriate arguemtns in main:

```
string s;
vector<int> arg;
vector<string> sv;
void someFunction (s, arg, sv ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing correct as the function you have declared 
`void add_county_election_file(const string, vector<int>&, vector<int>&,..);`

so you just have to call the above function with the required arguments, as right now you are not passing the argument and your current definition doesn't accepts any arguments.

And as a good practice, in your `int main()` function you can use `switch` rather than going for `if else`.

Answer (score 0):

- Store your variables and functions in a class, overload operators and create functions to access these variables.
- Declare all variables in `int main()` and set parameters to be passed into each function e.g.

  `void print_results()`  is modified to become

  `void print_results(std::vector<int> vec, int nCount, etc..)`
- Similar to the first one, create a struct to hold all data members, then pass the struct(by ref) into each function.

> ```
>  struct CountryTracker
>     {
>         std::vector<int> ID;
>         std::string name;
>         //etc...
>     }
> ```

```
`void print_results(CountryTracker& Obj) //pass single struct into functions`
```

Answer (score 0):

The OOP way to do this is to create a class called perhaps `ElectionInfo`, where:

These would be its member fields:

```
vector <string> countyNameVector;
vector <int> countyNCount;
vector <int> countyFCount;
vector <int> countyOCount;
int NCount;
int FCount;
int OCount;
int NTotal;
int FTotal;
int OTotal;
```

and these would be its member functions:

```
void add_county_election_file(const string);
void search_county(const string);
void print_results();
```

This way you don't have to pass the references to the vectors around at all, instead you can just do:

```
ElectionInfo an_elect_info;
char selection = get_menu_choice();

// some if-statements to decide which of the following to call:

an_elect_info.add_county_election_file(county_name);
an_elect_info.search_county(county_name);
an_elect_info.print_results();
```

But if you'd prefer to stay with the current functional approach:

Declare and initialize the following inside your main method:

```
vector <string> countyNameVector;
vector <int> countyNCount;
vector <int> countyFCount;
vector <int> countyOCount;
int NCount;
int FCount;
int OCount;
int NTotal;
int FTotal;
int OTotal;
```

The syntax for the commented out function declarations should be tweaked to look like this:

```
void add_county_election_file(const string, vector<string>&, vector<int>&, vector<int&, vector<int>&);
```

(Of course, the definition should follow suit)

You would invoke it like this:

```
add_county_election_file(countyname, countyNameVector, countyNCount, countyFCount, countyOCount);
```

Objects are automatically passed-by-reference.

Answer (score 0):

The basic process of refactoring should at the first step involve only code grouping and placement and should only minimally involve writing new logic. Using this as a principle you can go about modifying the code in the following way at first.

```
string ReadInputString(const char* title)
{
    string s

    cout << title;
    cin >> s;

}

void add_county_election_file(const std::string& filename
    , std::vector<string>& countyNameVector
    , std::vector<int>& countyNCount
    , std::vector<int>& countyFCount
    , std::vector<int>& countyOCount
    )
{
        int NCount = 0;
        int FCount = 0;
        int OCount = 0;
        int NTotal = 0;
        int FTotal = 0;
        int OTotal = 0;
        char vote;
    std::ifstream input((filename).c_str());
    string countyName;
    if(input.is_open())
        {
        input >> countyName;
        countyNameVector.push_back(countyName);
        while(input >> vote)
                        {
                        if(vote == 'N' || vote == 'n')
                                {
                NCount = NCount + 1;
                }
                                else if(vote == 'F' || vote == 'f')
                                        {
                                        FCount = FCount + 1;
                                        }
                                        else
                                                {
                                                OCount = OCount + 1;
                                                }
                        }
            countyNCount.push_back(NCount);
            countyFCount.push_back(FCount);
            countyOCount.push_back(OCount);
        }
        cout << countyName << endl;
}

void add_county_election_file()
{
  string fn = ReadInputString("Enter the county file to process: ");
  add_county_election_file(fn,g_countyNameVector,g_countyNCount,g_countyFCount,g_countyOCount);
}
```

As you can see I have just extracted your code and moved them to individual functions and changed names to make some significance. Like in the function ReadInputString - the line "cin >> s" was originally "cin >> filename". The abstract name "s" is to signify that the ReadInputString has no knowledge or doesn't care what the semantic meaning of the string it is reading from console.

In order to not change your main function - I have added a overloaded add_county_election_file that calls one function followed by another. The idea is that you should keep something unchanged and change others (for good) and then alternate if need be.
And I have changed names of your global variable to differentiate them from the local variable using "g_" - the point is that "g_" should only be found at very few places in your code.